# route.js routing with regular expressions

Tags: javascript

Using route.js, is it possible use a regular expression to specify routes?

Comment: *You are route.js?* So a javascript has just posted a question? Let's ban this bot!!! ;)

Comment: @ThiefMaster: he says he’s route.js _in his javascript scripts_.  Can’t you see he’s using his alter ego Salvatore to post a question? Tshsh... ;-P

Answer (score 1):

You can’t pass a regular expression to route.js.

What you could do instead, is write just one route, `route('#')`, and then match the `path` parameter of the first parameter that’s passed to all bound routines:

```
route('#').bind(function (page) {
    var regex = /(.*)/,
        match = regex.exec(page.path);
    if (match) {
      alert('We matched this path: ' + match[1] + '!');
    }
});
```

Be sure to check the [documentation](http://maraksquires.com/route.js/#/Learn/Route_Acquisition_101).